# Java: Why do the attributes of a child class change into the default values of the parent class by saving a child as a parent?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, parent-child

i´m still learning Java (and this is my first question on SO), so please forgive me if this kind of question is misplaced here or if my wording isn´t correct!

I´m looking into inheritance and polymorphism at the moment and weren´t able to answer the following question of mine, despite googling quite a few.

```
public class Animal {
    public String name = "Bello";

}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public String name = "Kitty";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        Animal animal1 = cat1;
        System.out.println(cat1.name);
        System.out.println(animal1.name);
    }
}
```

`System.out.println(cat1.name);` prints out `Kitty`, but `System.out.println(animal1.name);` prints out `Bello`

So apperently the value of the attribute *name* gets changed as the instance of the child class is saved as an object of the parent class. 
Why does the parent class change the value into her own default-value, even it is already set in *cat1*?
Seems there is sth. to know which i wasn´t able to figure out..

Comment: This is called _shadowing_; you have _two separate fields_ each named `name`. You're accessing different fields based on the compile-time type of the variables.

Comment: The concept is known as [field -or attribute-hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). It is part of Java's inheritance model. In general, it is regarded as "bad practice" to hide fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable with same name in parent and sub-class is known as variable hiding. But subclass will have access to both properties.

Access it using this and super keyword shown in below modified code

```
class Animal {
    public String name = "Bello";

}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public String name = "Kitty";

    Cat(){
        System.out.println(this.name); //Kitty
        System.out.println(super.name); //Bello
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        Animal animal1 = cat1;

        System.out.println(cat1.name);
        System.out.println(animal1.name);
    }
}
```